# Want to rename contact form fields name

Tags: 7, emails

I am using drupal 7 contact form in my site and I want to rename  some field names, like  "Subject" to "Emne" etc..

Comment: Refer to link : [LINK1](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/drupal-7-how-to-setup-contact-form-and-manage-contact-details.html)
 & [LINK2](http://willvincent.com/blog/adding-one-or-more-fields-drupal-7-contact-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` as shown below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_form_contact_site_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['subject']['#title'] = t('New Title');
}
```

### Update #1

For Page Title use [`drupal_set_title()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7) as shown below:

```
drupal_set_title('kontakt'); // Add this line in above function MODULENAME_form_contact_site_form_alter
```

Comment: Thanks.. I also want to rename page name contact to kontakt??

Comment: Check Update #1

Comment: can I change url http://localhost/drupal/?q=contact to http://localhost/drupal/?q=Kontakt?

Comment: Add url alias for this. You can manage it using pathauto(https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto).

Comment: But its comming from core drupal module contact

Comment: Pathauto has provision to add alias from backend